# Openlayers - Display data from geojson file in popup on map

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, geojson, popupwindow

I am working on an open layers map with different vector layers. I'm trying to show the information of the features in the geojson on the layer via a popup window. I found these two references:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zt2tyzqo/2/
- https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/GvdVNE

Thank you for any support. :)

This is the geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "dachnotnull",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 9, "GEBFLAECHE": 214.0, "GREENAR05": 13.0, "GREENAR20": 0.0, "SHAPE_AREA": 214.42924681599999, "SHAPE_LEN": 0.0, "p_intensiv": 0.060626058212800003, "p_extensiv": 0.0, "p_gesamt": 0.060626058212800003, "flaeche": 214.42924681599999 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":
```

This is the main.js:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Stamen from 'ol/source/Stamen';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import Vector from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Circle from 'ol/style/Circle';
import Fill from 'ol/style/Fill';
import Stroke from 'ol/style/Stroke';
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import {
  fromLonLat,
  toLonLat
} from 'ol/proj';
import sync from 'ol-hashed';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import {
  circular
} from 'ol/geom/Polygon';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import Control from 'ol/control/Control';
import * as olProj from 'ol/proj';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

// define the map
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([16.37, 48.2]),
    zoom: 13
  })
});

sync(map);

//Adresssuche
const searchResultSource = new Vector();
const searchResultLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: searchResultSource
});

searchResultLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  image: new Circle({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 1)'
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#000000',
      width: 1.25
    }),
    radius: 15
  })
}));

var element = document.getElementById('search');
element.addEventListener('keydown', listenerFunction);

function listenerFunction(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://photon.komoot.de/api/?q=' + element.value + '&limit=3');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      const geoJsonReader = new GeoJSON({
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      });
      searchResultSource.clear();
      const features = geoJsonReader.readFeatures(json);
      console.log(features);
      searchResultSource.addFeatures(features);
      if (!searchResultSource.isEmpty()) {
        map.getView().fit(searchResultSource.getExtent(), {
          maxZoom: 18,
          duration: 500
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.send();


  }
}

//OpenStreetMap
const OSMbaseLayer = new TileLayer({
  type: 'base',
  source: new OSM()
});

// Statellit
const satellitLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    attributions: ['Powered by Esri', 'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
    attributionsCollapsible: false,
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 30
  })
});

//shape
const parkLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new Vector({
    name: 'park',
    url: 'data/park1.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});

parkLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'green'
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 1.25
  }),
}));

const hitzeLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new Vector({
    name: 'hitze',
    url: 'data/hitze.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});

hitzeLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'red'
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'yellow',
    width: 1.25
  }),
}));

hitzeLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
  let fillColor;
  const hitzeindex = feature.get('AVG_UHVI_A');
  if (hitzeindex < 0.5) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(255, 228, 225, 0.7)';
  }  else if (hitzeindex < 0.75) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(240, 128, 128, 0.7)';
  } else {
    fillColor = 'rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.7)';
  }
  return new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: fillColor
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(4, 4, 4, 1)',
      width: 1
    })
  });
}); 

const dachLayer = new VectorLayer({
    minZoom: 17.9999,
    source: new Vector({
    name: 'dach',
    url: 'data/dachnotnull.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});


dachLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
  let fillColor;
  const begruenung = feature.get('p_gesamt');
  if (begruenung < 0.2) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(143, 188, 143, 1)';
  }  else if (begruenung < 0.4) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(60, 179, 113, 1)';
  } else if (begruenung < 0.6) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(46, 139, 87, 1)';
  } else if (begruenung < 0.8) {
    fillColor = 'rgba(34, 139, 34, 1)';
  } else {
    fillColor = 'rgba(0, 100, 0, 1)';
  }
  return new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: fillColor
    })
  });
});

// Layer hinzufügen
map.addLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
dachLayer.setZIndex(15);
parkLayer.setZIndex(10);
hitzeLayer.setZIndex(5);

// gruenflaechen layer anzeigen
const park = document.getElementById('park');
park.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("park");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    parkLayer.setMap(map);
    // parkLayer.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    parkLayer.setMap(undefined);
    //parkLayer.setVisible(false);
  }
});

// hitze layer anzeigen
const hitze = document.getElementById('hitze');
hitze.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("hitze");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    hitzeLayer.setMap(map);
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(false);
    hitzeLayer.setMap(undefined);
  }
});

// dach layer anzeigen
const dach = document.getElementById('dach');
dach.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("dach");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    dachLayer.setMap(map);
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    //hitzeLayer.setVisible(false);
    dachLayer.setMap(undefined);
  }
}); 


// Get the OSMbase Base-Button
const OSMbase = document.getElementById('OSMbase');
OSMbase.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  //contr.style.color = 'ffffff';
  //Andere Layer entfernen
  map.removeLayer(satellitLayer);
  map.removeLayer(searchResultLayer);
  //OSM Layer hinzufügen
  map.addLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
  map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
});

// Get the satellit Base-Button
const satellit = document.getElementById('satellit');
satellit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  //Andere Layer entfernen
  map.removeLayer(OSMbaseLayer);
  map.removeLayer(searchResultLayer);
  //Satelliten Layer hinzufügen
  map.addLayer(satellitLayer);
  map.addLayer(searchResultLayer);
});

//GPS Location
const GPSsource = new Vector();
const GPSlayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: GPSsource
});
map.addLayer(GPSlayer);


navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (pos) {
  const coords = [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude];
  const accuracy = circular(coords, pos.coords.accuracy);
  GPSsource.clear(true);
  GPSsource.addFeatures([
    new Feature(accuracy.transform('EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection())),
    new Feature(new Point(fromLonLat(coords)))
  ]);
}, function (error) {
  alert(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
}, {
  enableHighAccuracy: true
});

const locate = document.createElement('div');
locate.className = 'ol-control ol-unselectable locate';
locate.innerHTML = '<button title="Locate me">◎</button>';
locate.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (!GPSsource.isEmpty()) {
    map.getView().fit(GPSsource.getExtent(), {
      maxZoom: 18,
      duration: 500
    });
  }
});

map.addControl(new Control({
  element: locate
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a overlay to your map object;
use setPosition of your overlay object to snap to a point

example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

api: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Overlay-Overlay.html